# Ignite web console backend not working - Error: Not Found: /signup

Tags: caching, ignite, gridgain

I am running Apache Ignite 2.4.0 and configured Ignite web console using following steps [Ignite webconsole build and deploy](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/build-and-deploy)

same has been configured for production mode in Apache server and after successfully starting Backend, when i access web console from front end I am getting below signup error on Backend Node application console. I have tried multiple configurations but none of them seems to work.

```
Error: Not Found: /signup
    at app.use (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/app/apiServer.js:64:33)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:325:9)
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:71:10)
    at attempt (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:348:16)
    at authenticate (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:349:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at initialize (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/initialize.js:53:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/recon/Ignite/web-console/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: Could you update your question with Ignite version you are trying to deploy

Comment: hi  kuaw26 i have updated Ignite version i.e, 2.4.0

Comment: Hi, Sandy. I will take a look and post an answer in a couple of days.

Comment: Hi @kuaw26 thanks for your response, early reply is much helpful as this has been blocker for me since couple of weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snady, ignite-2.5.0 is on vote now and may be released in several days. I think it make sense to use this version.

Requirements: NodeJS 8.x & MongoDB 3.4.x. // Make sure you have this.

So, I downloaded sources and do the following:

1. In first terminal:

   cd {apache-ignite-2.5.0}/modules/web-console/backend

   npm install --no-optional

   npm start
2. In second terminal:

   cd {apache-ignite-2.5.0}/modules/web-console/frontend

   npm install --no-optional

   npm start
3. In browser do: http://localhost:9000/

EDIT:
Will Ignite Web Console in Docker works for your case?
See: https://hub.docker.com/r/apacheignite/web-console-standalone/

Comment: Hi kuaw thanks for quick reply but I have few limitations in above approach, there is no net connectivity in my sit environment so i cannot exactly do "npm install --no-optional" , as a workaround I have built frontend in my local windows machine and moved same to Apache /var/www/web-console folder in SIT environment, apache is up and running but i cannot start frontend from "npm start", In the same way I have built backend from local and moved to SIT, as stated earlier when access webconsole from browser i can see the request in backend node logs but it is giving  "Error: Not Found: /signup"

Comment: OK, I will try to "simulate" your setup on Monday